# How to place a plsql block inside a sequence

Tags: plsql

I am trying to create a user generated sequence. According to usual syntax of oracle sequence we can start with a number and increment a value.
Is there a method to write a plsql block (declare begin end) inside a sequence and generate my own sequnce.

example :  ABC001
When i call the next val of sequence , the value should be ABC002

Answer (score 1):

PLEASE CLEAR FIRST WHAT YOU EXACTLY WANT TO ASK.

If you are asking HOW TO DYNAMICALLY CREATE SEQUENCE USING PL/SQL, then check below.

Simplest way.

```
DECLARE
    SQL_S VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    SQL_S := 'CREATE SEQUENCE SQN_NAME INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_S;
END;
/
```

If you want to dynamically create sequence with some DYNAMIC name as argument passed to procedure, then it will be like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DYNAMIC_SQN (ARG IN VARCHAR2) IS
    SQL_S VARCHAR2(100);
    PARAM1 VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
    PARAM1 := 'SQN_NAME_' || ARG;
    SQL_S := 'CREATE SEQUENCE ' || PARAM1 || ' INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_S;
END;
/
```

And if you simply want to insert in to any column, and create the PK using it in addition to some String, then

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_T VALUES('ABC'|| SEQUENCE_NAME.nextval, OTHER_VALUES);
```

It will still give you values like : `ABC1`, `ABC2`, .... `ABC12`, `ABC13`, .... `ABC99`, `ABC100` and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Considering the sample example you have given i m writing the following code

create your sequence, then

```
insert into seq values('ABC'||YOURSEQUENCENAME.nextval,YOUR_VALUE);
```